# Menu "Hamburger" icon won't appear, but text does appear

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm working on the topbar for my website using foundation, everything seems to be working fine except the menu icon does not appear, I followed the foundation docs and I'm still having issues. What I have looks like something like this:

```
<header class="contain-to-grid">
<!-- Starting the Top-Bar -->
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name"/>

           <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>


    <section class="top-bar-section">

            <ul class="left">
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                <li >
                    <a href="#">page1</a>
                </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">page2</a>
                </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                <li >
                     <a href="#">page3</a>
                </li> 
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>


            <!--Search in top bar-->
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="has-form">
                    <div class="row collapse">
                        <div>
                            <div class="large-8 small-8 columns">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-4 small-4 columns">
                                  <a href="#" class="button expand">Search</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </ul>

    </section>

</nav>

<!-- End of Top-Bar -->
</header>
```

"Menu" does appear and work properly, but the menu icon never does. If I remove "Menu" nothing appears and I cannot use the menu at all.

Comment: Can you give us your entire source code? from the looks of it, you're using some kind of framework or something. A small snippet doesn't really help much in this case - or even better recreate the situation in jsfiddle or something

Comment: @KevinPei I edited my question, I'm using the Foundation framework like I stated in my question.

Comment: Please include CSS and if you could put it in jsfiddle or similar we will be more than glad of help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the solution. You have to import the CSS from Foundation that seems like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
```

Foundation use Media Queries. That means you have to resize your browser window current to 40.063em.